# Orientation change breaks view controller alignment, if changed while drawer is closing via pan gesture recognizer

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

In the iOS app, attempting to close a "drawer" using a pan gesture while simultaneously changing the device orientation causes the "center" view controller to become misaligned. I'm experiencing this on version 0.1.28 on an iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.

This is reproducible on the demo project that comes with [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) in the iOS 6.0 or 7.0 simulators, so it looks like the problem originates with MMDrawerController.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open either drawer in portrait, or landscape mode.
2. Begin panning, as if to close the drawer.
3. Without releasing your finger, change the device orientation.
4. Continue to pan.

Side Effects:

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/issues/204, https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/issues/228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed on version 0.1.29. Thanks for catching this issue.